# Calculating values of a list of vectors by rows with purrr and reduce

Tags: r, purrr

I have this map here that returns a list of vectors of lags, using purrr:map.

```
purrr:map(0:2,~ lag(1:10, .x))
```

> [[1]]
>   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
>
> [[2]]
>   [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
>
> [[3]]
>   [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8

I'm interested in calculating averages for rows if those vectors were combined into a tibble.

I know I can sum rows using rows. So, for example,

```
reduce(map(0:2,~ lag(1:10, .x)), `+`)
```

> [1] NA NA  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27

However, when I try:

```
reduce(map(0:2,~ lag(1:10, .x)), ~ mean(.x, na.rm=T))
```

> 5.5

This is not the answer I'm interested in. How do I do that using purrr?

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong, you have 4 open and only 3 closed ones.

Comment: It was just a typo, it's not a problem with my code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variant of `pmap` to loop through all three vectors simultaneously.  Because `mean` takes a vector of numbers, though, I used an anonymous function to concatenate the three elements together via `c`.

`pmap_dbl` returns a vector of numbers.

```
map(0:2, ~lag(1:10, .x) ) %>%
     pmap_dbl( function(a, b, c) mean( c(a, b, c), na.rm = TRUE) )

[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0
```

The development version has added `..1` type coding with the tilde to refer to each list.

```
map(0:2, ~lag(1:10, .x) ) %>%
     pmap_dbl( ~mean( c(..1, ..2, ..3), na.rm = TRUE) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate data frame does not look very pretty, but it still works as intended:

```
purrr::map(0:2,~ lag(1:10, .x)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% rowMeans(na.rm=TRUE)
```